# I didn't press Alt to smooth when creating edge loops is this fixable?

Tags: edges

so I was watching a tutorial for making a hard surface airplane, only after a long time did I notice the presenter was selecting the edge loop, pressing alt then dragging it, which apparently is different than just dragging it.  so now my model is more jaggy. Can I reapply that effect to a loop?

Comment: Are you sure the lesson author didn't press `G` twice after selecting a loop?  So It could be useful to know what exactly was done in the lesson (it may be eaiser to provide a link with time mentioning). Regarding to `Alt` - it is pressed to select adjacent loop instead of one edge/vertex/face.